# getting article (by Id) intro text into a custom module

Tags: get, article

I'm developing a custom module in joomla 4 which needs to access the introtext of a specific article whose Id is known.

I'm looking for a code snippet that follows the latest coding standards and is most likely to continue to work properly when joomla 5 appears rather than something jotted down on the back of an envelope.

have not tried anything yet so nothing has happened yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the introtext from _content table with sql query

```
/**
 * Get the introtext of an article
 * @param int $articleID
 * @return string the introtext
 */
function getArticleIntrotext($articleID) {
    $db = Factory::getContainer()->get('DatabaseDriver');
    // basic sql query... SELECT introtext FROM #__content WHERE id = $articleID
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select($db->quoteName('introtext'))
        ->from($db->quoteName('#__content'))
        ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . $articleID);
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $introtext = $db->loadResult();

    return $introtext;

}
```

Comment: The snippet does not work in my custom module. Aren't there some missing "use" statements? I'm thinking there needs to be something like

Comment: yeah you need to use factory

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

Comment: when I add that I get a php error complaining '0 syntax error, unexpected token "use" '. I must still be missing at least one arcane directive.